# Testing a simple qt console program on non-qt-installed pc

Tags: qt, console

The code is very simple:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc,argv);
    qDebug()<<"Hello world!";
    return a.exec();
}
```

And the .pro file's content is:

```
CONFIG+=qt debug console
SOURCES+=a.cpp
TARGET=trytoshow
```

I used the dumpbin utility to find out on which .dll the console program depends:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>dumpbin -dependents "G:\Public\H
ello world\trytoshow.exe"
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file G:\Public\Hello world\trytoshow.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

Image has the following dependencies:

```
QtGuid4.dll
QtCored4.dll
MSVCR90D.dll
KERNEL32.dll
```

Summary

```
    1000 .data
    1000 .idata
    2000 .rdata
    1000 .rsrc
    4000 .text
```

So I put the trytoshow.exe, qtguid4.dll, qtcored4.dll and a folder named "Debug_NonRedist", which is from 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist, into a directory. Then I released it to a non-qt-installed pc.
It does not run.

Did I do anything wrong? Thank you.

Comment: "do not run" means what? Any error? warning?

Comment: "does not run" means the windows system consider that some .dll files which the program depends on do not exist. But I have used the dumpbin utility to find out which files.

Comment: And meanwhile I released the program under release mode with the files the release version needs. It works on the non-qt-installed pc. I can not find the reason, why debug version does not run, and release version does.

Comment: You said the "the windows system consider that some .dll files which the program depends on do not exist", I remember that, the error message should tell you which dll is missing, right?

Comment: NO, it did not tell me. it said:
This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Comment: I just created one simple console program without Qt library. The same situation occured. I thought maybe the files in the folder Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT were wrong. I found out these files which I debuged under IDE on my computer, and overwrited those on the non-qt-installed pc. The same situation still occured. I think maybe there is some policy preventing debug-version program running on the non-qt-installed pc. Is it possible?

Comment: This is the problem that the runtime is not suitable for your application in target machine. You can simply use static runtime library link so solve this problem.

Comment: But I do not understand why it is not suitable. It works under my devoloping computer, and it does not work under the one not installed with VS2008. The only reason I can image is the debug version C runtime library is forbidden on that computer.
I have change the name of the debug version folder of VS2008 in WinSXS. It result in neither of the debug version of the program (the one under IDE VS2008 or the one with debug version C runtime library in my developing computer) does not work. However, the warning is different from the other computer. It showed initialization failed.

Comment: It is weird. Why did not the one not under VS2008 IDE use the debug version C runtime library? I think both of the two computers have the same policy forbidding the debug version of C runtime library. The two computers are the company's assets.

Comment: There should no be forbidden, just do not match. But I am not sure how to make them match exactly with any tools. You may try depends.exe in your VS tools, it can display the dependent dll that a exe required.

Answer (score 0):

As winterTTr already pointed out in the comment to your post, it would be important to know what "It does not run" really means.

There could be more dependencies used by the (Qt) Dll's, so I would suggest to have a look at the ouput of Dependency Walker when you start the program to find out what might be missing (you can use the "Profiling" functionality of the program to do that). You can find it here: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I have downloaded the dependencywalker. And this utility shows the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a debug version of your program, you should also use the debug version of the relevant dlls. If i remember correctly, there is debug version of Qt dll, such as `QtCored4.dll`, `QtGui4d.dll`, and etc.

On the other hand,
if you find "This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect", normally, this is because the debug version runtime library on the target machine may not be same as where you compile it. So, you can use static runtime library link for your application, that should solve this problem.

For vs2010, Under Configuration Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library -> MultiThreaded (/MTd), which is the /MTd compile parameter for cl.exe. You can also try to find how to set it in qt application.

Comment: Yes, Ijust used the debug version of the qt, such as qtcored4.dll and qtguid4.dll. The utility showed what I need from qt is just qtcored4.dll and qtguid4.dll.